# Computational methods to minimizing the norm of a matrix monomial.

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization

Linear optimization solves the problem $$\min_{\bf x}\{\|{\bf Ax - b}\|_2^2\}$$

---

**Edit: Some clarification**

Doing the derivation of the optimum, first expand the norm: $$\|{\bf Ax - b}\|_2^2 = ({\bf Ax-b})^T({\bf Ax-b}) = {\bf x}^T{\bf A}^T{\bf Ax} - {\bf x}^T{\bf A}^T{\bf b} - {\bf b}^T{\bf Ax} + {\bf b}^T{\bf b}$$
Then when differentiating this expression with respect to $\bf x$ and setting equal to the zero vector, we do get a linear equation system $${\bf A}^T{\bf Ax}= {\bf A}^T{\bf b}$$
So we see that for any $\bf A$, the left hand side is a non negative matrix. If we add $\lambda {\bf I}$, with $\lambda > 0$, corresponding to $\lambda\|{\bf x}\|_2^2$ in the optimization, we would be sure to have a positive definite system.

---

In algebra many non-linear things can be expressed as ${\bf M}^k$ thanks to representation theory, that group elements can be represented as matrices. Famous examples include rotating on a circle or a sphere (rotation matrices) and cyclic groups. In some sense turning a non-linear concept into a linear one.

So say I instead want to solve the problem.
$$\min_{k}\{\|{{\bf A}^k{\bf x - b}}\|_2^2\}$$
or even
$$\min_{k}\{\|{{\bf A}^k - {\bf M}}\|_2^2\}$$

What are your favourite methods to attack these kinds of problems?

---

**Own "work"**

I suppose one could view it as minimizing a multivariable polynomial equation system, as the ${\bf A}_{ij}$ gets multiplied and summed up in $k$ scalar products for each element. Minimizing such a function should be a multivariate polynomial equation system ( setting each partial differential, which is also a multivariate polynomial = 0 ). However I have no Idea how fruitful it would be to try and search for such a solution or if there are better approaches.

Comment: Coming from the numerical linear algebra side... would $x$ in $$\min_{k}\{\|{{\bf A}^k{\bf x - b}}\|_2^2\}$$ be fixed?  Or do you want to minimize over $k$ and $x$?  Also, I think you should take a look at GMRes.  You could easily take advantage of the way Krylov subspaces are built to get information about $k$.

Comment: Great question! Yes probably in the end I want to minimize wrt $\bf x$ too. I have done conjugate gradient minimizing wrt $\bf x$ in two steps for $k=2$, "baking in" each intermediate solution into $\bf b$. It can give a reasonable result in some cases, but not as good as (I think) should be possible. For some reason my most conveniently available implementation runs out of memory when running GMRes. But I probably should read more in depth about it.

Comment: Have you tried restarts?

Comment: Yes now that you mention it.. gmres is one of these Krylov methods which needs to store a whole matrix and not just a vector and default restart value was the dimensionality of the vector. No wonder I ran out of memory as my vector was $10^5$ values :)

Comment: If you could provide a little more information about $A$ (you mentioned earlier you had used conjugate gradients, so I presume it is at least symmetric positive definite?), I could provide a more problem-specific list of methods.  Considering again your main problem, I realize that neither CG nor GMRes may be suited to what you want.

Comment: The matrix when solving the least squares becomes symmetric positive definite, as the norm gives $A^TA$ in the left hand side of the equation system. We aren't solving $Ax = b$, but minimising the two norm of an expression involving $A$. So for any $A$ we would be getting a symmetric matrix involving $A^TA$, often we need a small $\lambda\|x\|_2$ to ensure positive definiteness though.

Comment: Regarding your update: solving the system of normal equations is not a good idea.  This leads to a squaring of the condition number in convergence results-- meaning, convergence is slow at best, impossible at worse.  This is perhaps why CG did not give you good results so far.

Comment: But it is not the normal equations to the system. The problem is a minimization problem, when we derive it's solution by evaluating the norm and differentiating w.r.t. vector $\bf v$ then $A^TA$ pops out as a term in the matrix side of the equation system. The normal equations to the system would be something like $(A^TA)^T(A^TA)$.